# Tix and Python 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, tix

Has anyone seen anything in Tix work under python 3.0?  I've tried to work through the examples but when creating anything it states that cnf is unsubscriptable.

I also noticed that none of the Dir Select stuff (DirList DirTree) works under 2.6.1.

Why doesn't Python either dump Tix or support it?  Its got a lot of good stuff to make easy programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely what happened is that no one noticed the bug. (It's very hard to automatically test GUI libraries like Tix and Tkinter.) You should report bugs as you find them to http://bugs.python.org.

Comment: There is a bug registered for the 2.6 release for Tix.  I'm going to move back to 2.5.4, because it works.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you're using third-party modules, you're better off avoiding Python 3.0 for now.  If you're working on a third-party module yourself, porting forward to Python 3.0 is a good idea, but for the time being general development in it is just going to be a recipe for pain.

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.tix.html?highlight=tix#module-tkinter.tix